# How to call an API dynamically in functional programming paradigm

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, clean-architecture

My application receives http requests from humain clients.

My application needs to call only one API, among 12 other APIs, depending on one specific data in the input it receives.

My first thought was of course

```js
// requestPrice.js

const service = req.body.service

const APIs = {
    ser1: callAPI1,
    ser2: callAPI2,
    ser3: callAPI3,
    // ...
    ser12: callAPI12,
}

return APIs[service](req.body)
```

This works fine but I guess needs some refactoring to make it SOLID compliant.
Normally in OOP I would go with one of the design patterns such as strategy or chain of responsibility maybe.

However I'm using the functional programming so a bit different.

I thought of doing the following:

```js
// ser1.js
export default callAPI(data) {
    // code 1
}

// ser2.js
export default callAPI(data) {
    // code 2
}

// ser3.js
export default callAPI(data) {
    // code 3
}

//...

// ser12.js
export default callAPI(data) {
    // code 12
}

// requestPrice.js
const service = req.body.service
const api = require(`./${service}`)

return api(req.body)
```

This looks much better than the first version as it follows much better the Single responsibility principle. Plus it follows Open/Closed principle as well, I guess, as the `requestPrice.js` won't change if a 13th api is to be added.
In the other hand, I should be able to easily unit test even the file `requestPrice.js` as the `req` can be injected.

Is it SOLID principles compliant to do so or is there a better and cleaner way?

Comment: Nice effort but I don't think it complies to Dependency Inversion principle, because the request body has to know the details of which service to call. It should however, know just the input. Agree?

Comment: It's the other way round actually. `req.body.service` is the name of the API to call. It's juste a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a factory method (implemented as a curried function in FP) so that decision of which service to call and what to do in each service becomes separated. request.body should be passed to the returned impl function.

```
function createService(body) {
  if(checkInput(body) == [something]) return service1;
  else if(checkInput(body) == [something2]) return service2;
  ..
}

function service1(body) {..}
function service2(body) {..}
..

let service = createService(req.body);
service(request.body);
```

I haven't put it in different files but you may do so. Now createService can be in a different module. And each impl (service1, service2, etc) can be in their own separate files, and the caller of service doesn't need to know which impl to call, hence maintaining Dependency inversion. Higher level module doesn't know about the lower level module. :)

Comment: I like that! This encapsulates in the factory the code choosing amongst services. Yeah I should've considered that before.
Thanks! 

PS: I may wait a bit for another answer